# Gradle 5, maven deployer: unknown property uniqueVersion

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, mavendeployer

I use eclipse with gradle buildship. My `build.gradle` contains

```
uploadArchives { 
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {            
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars
            uniqueVersion = false

            repository(url: 'dav:http://...') {
                authentication(userName: '...', password: '...')
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: 'dav:http://...') {
                authentication(userName: '...', password: '...')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This leads to the error message

```
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution
'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-bin.zip'.
...
Could not set unknown property 'uniqueVersion' for object of type 
org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same error when I attempted to build an old project in Android Studio 3.4, with Android SDK version 28.  The old project was built using Android Studio 2.2.3 and Android SDK version 23.

I just commented out the line `uniqueVersion = False`, did a clean rebuild an viola, no more errors.

Comment: I commented it out, too, and there were no more problems.

Comment: @Johannes Flügel glad it helped!  Would you mind selecting mine as the answer to your question?